# what this error means in predictions on test set in WEKA

Tags: weka, data-mining, data-analysis

I am a beginner on using WEKA. The problem is when I am trying to test a new dataset on my model by using supplied test set choice, the prediction is OK but it gives + signs in error field what is that mean?. In addition, confusion matrix and accuracy details gave some cells empty.

```
== Predictions on test set ===

inst#     actual  predicted error prediction
    1    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
    2    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
    3    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
    4    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
    5    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
    6    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
    7    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
    8    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
    9    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   10    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   11    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   12    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   13    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   14    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   15    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   16    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   17    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   18    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   19    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   20    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   21    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   22    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   23    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   24    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   25    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   26    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   27    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   28    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   29    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   30    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   31    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   32    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   33    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   34    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   35    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   36    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   37    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   38    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   39    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   40    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   41    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   42    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   43    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   44    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   45    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   46    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   47    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   48    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   49    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   50    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   51    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   52    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   53    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   54    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   55    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   56    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   57    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   58    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   59    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   60    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   61    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   62    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   63    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   64    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   65    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   66    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   67    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   68    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   69    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   70    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   71    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   72    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   73    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   74    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   75    2:' ST'      1: NT   +   1 
   76    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   77    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   78    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   79    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   80    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   81    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   82    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   83    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   84    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   85    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   86    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   87    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   88    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   89    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   90    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   91    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   92    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   93    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   94    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   95    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   96    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   97    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   98    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
   99    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  100    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  101    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  102    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  103    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  104    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  105    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  106    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  107    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  108    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  109    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  110    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  111    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  112    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  113    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  114    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  115    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  116    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  117    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  118    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  119    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  120    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  121    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  122    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  123    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  124    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  125    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  126    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  127    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  128    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  129    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  130    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  131    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  132    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  133    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  134    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  135    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  136    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  137    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  138    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  139    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  140    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  141    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  142    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  143    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  144    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  145    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  146    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  147    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  148    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  149    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 
  150    1:' NT'      1: NT       1 

=== Evaluation on test set ===

Time taken to test model on supplied test set: 0.13 seconds

=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances          75               50      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances        75               50      %
Kappa statistic                          0     
Mean absolute error                      0.5   
Root mean squared error                  0.7071
Relative absolute error                100      %
Root relative squared error            141.4214 %
Total Number of Instances              150     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 1.000    1.000    0.500      1.000    0.667      ?        0.500     0.500      NT
                 0.000    0.000    ?          0.000    ?          ?        0.500     0.500      ST
Weighted Avg.    0.500    0.500    ?          0.500    ?          ?        0.500     0.500     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

  a  b   <-- classified as
 75  0 |  a =  NT
 75  0 |  b =  ST
```

Is it possible that all ST predicted wrong?
I searched a lot to figure out the problem with no results.

the training and testing data are compatible and the testing data are labeled.

Comment: Yes. This definitely is possible.

Comment: what + sign mean? what if all accuracy details filled by the question mark?

Comment: Obviously this indicates an error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the confusion matrix, all of your predictions are `NT`. So all instances labeled as `ST` are predicted as `NT`.